# Event binding to each LinkButton of Repeater not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, eventhandler

I need set a button for each item of repeater in C#(asp.net).

```
<com:Repeater runat="server" ID="list_repeater">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'>Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</com:Repeater>
```

I bind data in PageLoad.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        list_repeater.DataSource = ... getData ..;
        list_repeater.DataBind();
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, i bind RepeaterItemEventHandler on the list.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    base.LoadingControlAdd();
    ...
    list_repeater.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(list_repeater_ItemDataBound);
    ...
}
```

and then i bind EventHandler to each btnCancel.

```
protected void list_repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        LinkButton btnCancel = e.Item.FindControl("btnCancel") as LinkButton;
        btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(btnCancel_Click);
    }
}
```

But, it does not work. 
When i click the btnCancel of each item, **btnCancel_Click** is not triggered. I think i does well, and can't find any flaw. Is there any fault on the code above please tell me what's wrong. Thanks.
(id on CommnadArgument is set properly, don't mind it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Solved.**

Refer: https://forums.asp.net/t/1680429.aspx?bind+event+handler+for+dynamic+controls+in+repeater

> As far as I know, "itemDataBound" event is used when you call DataBind(). However, a databind process can usually be done in the body of if (!IsPostBack)｛……｝,So you can never call DataBind() any more, I guess the reason is this.
>
> To solve the problem, You can try to put the codes like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        list_repeater.DataSource = ... getData ..;
        list_repeater.DataBind();
        ...
    }
    ...
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in list_repeater.Items) {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            LinkButton btnCancel = item.FindControl("btnCancel") as LinkButton;
            btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(btnCancel_Click);
        }
    }
```

It's caused by my poor knowledge for asp.net. Sorry for self-answering in minutes after post the question.